# Circuit repair - how to find the value of a burned-out resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have a circuit that supplies 230V mains power to an 8W fluorescent tube (something like [this](https://www.lighting.philips.com/main/prof/conventional-lamps-and-tubes/fluorescent-lamps-and-starters/tl-miniature/tl-mini-standard-colours/928001003318_EU/product)). Resistor "?" has released its magic smoke, and is blackened to the point where I can't read the resistor value.

[image]

this is the circuit with the lamp attached:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to calculate the value based on the rest of the circuit?

Comment: Are you sure the schematic is correct ? Looks like a bridge rectifier but with AC connection at the wrong points. What is the load marked by the X ?

Comment: I'm wondering if that's actually supposed to be a charge pump to aid in starting the tube. Photo of both sides of the board may help

Comment: the load marked by X is a fluorescent tube. I've added a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up try measuring it. Often, even though it has started to burn, it won't have gone open circuit and may be not that far off its original value.

Otherwise, the circuits does not indeed look quite right. Double check with layout. Also some explanation of its function might help.

EDIT : if the resistor has gone open circuit, the real question is why. It generally needs a resistor to operate over its maximum power for a good few seconds to make it really do this. I would hesitate about repairing such a circuit because of the possibility that some other component might be failing (possibly only when its under high voltage). Also these direct main connected circuits are very hard to work on and diagnose in a safe manner. Unless there is a compelling reason to get it going, I'd be inclined to bin it.

Comment: I measured the resistor: it's open circuit. It's possible I misinterpreted the layout, of course.

Comment: where are the two terminal blocks on your circuit?

Comment: The terminal block on the right is where the 230V mains is attached. It's top right on the circuit diagram. The terminal block on the left is where the lamp is attached.

Comment: it's a $20 device that's 20 years old. Repairing it would be an interesting exercise but it's not critical, so in the bin it goes.